How to write a Regex that targets the first match in each line only?
I want to copy past a huge list of properties rather than type them all out again. However I want to avoid copy their assignments.
The solution I'm trying involves a cmdF regex in VSCode. Then selecting all found matches.
Sample of typescript code.
    this.anchorBillingAddress = this.page.getByTestId('billing-address-section');
    this.anchorShippingAddress = this.page.getByTestId('shipping-address-section');
    this.anchorBilling = this.page.getByTestId('billing-section');
    this.anchorGeneral = this.page.getByTestId('general-section');
    this.anchorStatistics = this.page.getByTestId('statistics-section');

Expected output would be:
this.anchorBillingAddress

this.anchorShippingAddress

this.anchorBilling

this.anchorGeneral

this.anchorStatistics

this[^\s]+
is what I have tried. However it ends up copying the assignment as well. How do I make it stop at the first white space encountered in each line?

You can use:

\b(this\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+)(?=\s*=)
\b(this\.\w+)(?=\s*=) or
^\s*\b(this\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+)(?=\s*=)

to find the first this..


const p = /\b(this\.\w+)(?=\s*=)/gm;
const s = `    this.anchorBillingAddress = this.page.getByTestId(

'billing-address-section'

);
    this.anchorShippingAddress = this.page.getByTestId(

'shipping-address-section'

)

;
    this.anchorBilling = this.page.getByTestId('billing-section');
    this.anchorGeneral = this.page.getByTestId('general-section');
    this.anchorStatistics = this.page.getByTestId('statistics-section');`;

const matches = s.match(p);
if (matches) {
  matches.forEach((match, index) => {
    console.log(`${index}=> ${match}`);
  });
}




Note:

\s*: 0 or more spaces.
\b: is the word boundary.
(this\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+)(?=\s*=): captures from this. to the first \s or =. [A-Za-z0-9_] is same as \w.
(?=\s*=): positive lookahead, which matches the pattern \s*= right after the this\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+.


In VS Code, first copy the lines to their target destination and then:

hit Ctrl+H to open the find/replace popup

toggle regex support on with Alt+R  if not yet active

type ^\s*(this\.\w+).* in the find box

type $1 in the replace box:


hit Ctrl+Alt+Enter to perform the replacements.



Works in a way. I'm not trying to replace anything. But I was able to copy what was left after the replace action and cmd+Z to undo the action.

OK, but I see you accepted another answer, so I guess you didn't need my answer.

If you want it to stop at the first space, you can do this
^this[^\s]+
The ^ makes sure it's from the start and won't grab the second this.

This didn't work. It says no results.

Do you have another character before the this? Like a tab or space?  This regex assumes this is the first set of characters on the line.

yes I do, this code is all encapsulated within in a class constructor

Ah ok, and I know you've already accepted but you could just prepend with spaces, if that's what they are to ^\s*this[^\s]+ - I'm curious now

I tried that, still no luck. It doesn't match anything on the page.

You can try /this\.\S+(?=\s*=)/g
This will give you all left hand side assignment parts starting with "this.".


const text=`let a = this.currentDate;
this.anchorBillingAddress = this.page.getByTestId('billing-address-section');
// a comment
this.anchorShippingAddress = this.page.getByTestId('shipping-address-section');
let b = this.should.not.be.captured;
console.log(this.property);
this.anchorBilling = this.page.getByTestId('billing-section');
this.anchorGeneral = this.page.getByTestId('general-section');
this.anchorStatistics = this.page.getByTestId('statistics-section');`;

console.log(text.match(/this\.\S+(?=\s*=)/g));



The positive lookahead (?=\s*=) makes sure, that the captured text must be directly followed by any number of whitespace followed by an equal sign ("=").

No luck. This returns "no results"
